# Using Google Earth Engine to filter Landsat Daytime image?

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat-8

How do I filter Landsat imageCollection by their time of collection?

For example, if they are daytime or nighttime, which might be specified as Ascending or Descending.

I don't know which metadata keyword to use for filtering out by that.

Comment: Is that what you need or is just an example? The property that holds the exact time is `system:time_start`, but depending in what you need you may need to process it

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 4):

The property that holds the exact time is `system:time_start`

For example, to get the latest available image in some collection:

```js
// some collection
var s2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
// some place    
var p = ee.Geometry.Point(-72, -43)
// filter the collection by the place
s2 = s2.filterBounds(p)
// sort descending by time
var descending = s2.sort('system:time_start', false)
// get latest image (first of the collection)
var latest = ee.Image(descending.first())

print(latest.date())
```