# Querying Landsat 8 night images in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, query, landsat-8, night-time-images

Apparently, Landsat 8 occasionally acquires images at night-time during ascending passes. However, in the Google Earth Engine data catalogue (https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/LANDSAT_LC08_C01_T1_RT), there is no parameter like "orbit" or "pass".

Is there any other way to filter the Landsat 8 image collection for those night images?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `system:time_start` property as explained here:

[Using Google Earth Engine to filter Landsat Daytime image?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/302157/using-google-earth-engine-to-filter-landsat-daytime-image)

it contains the exact acquisition time. 
For example, get the latest available image in some collection:

```
// some collection
var s2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
// some place    
var p = ee.Geometry.Point(-72, -43)
// filter the collection by the place
s2 = s2.filterBounds(p)
// sort descending by time
var descending = s2.sort('system:time_start', false)
// get latest image (first of the collection)
var latest = ee.Image(descending.first())
```