# Filter out daytime image of LANDSAT 8 using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat-8

I saw an answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/302157/using-google-earth-engine-to-filter-landsat-daytime-image) saying that we should sort by 'system:time_start' but shouldn't that refer to the date (like 2015-05-01) instead of hour of the day? I also tried something like `ee.Filter.calendarRange(7, 15, 'hour')` but it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

About using `ee.Filter.calendarRange()` - you might have expected that images in certain location will be coming at different hours. In many areas, it's not a case. Also,`ee.Filter.calendarRange()` is way to go (you should avoid using `.sort` as suggested in other example for many reasons).

In the example below all the images for given locations were taken between ~10:38-10:41.

I've added an example of using `ee.Filter.calendarRange()`, showing that it does what it is expected to do.

```
var l8 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2"),
    geometry = /* color: #d63000 */ee.Geometry.Point([-1.6843750000000135, 31.62971723875741]);
    
var ic = l8.filterBounds(geometry)

print("Size of filtered image collection", ic.size())

// What time of the day images were taken?
print("SCENE_CENTER_TIME histogram", ic.aggregate_histogram("SCENE_CENTER_TIME"))

print("Filter includes 10am", ic.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(10,17,"hour")).size())
print("Filter excludes 10am", ic.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(11,17,"hour")).size())
```

Here is the link to the example:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/005c8c3616ee0371b6cdf9597d91f095

Next time include an example script illustrating what didn't work for you.

I hope, it helps. Good luck with your analysis!

Comment: Thanks a bunch! It really helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SUN_ELEVATION` property to filter out daytime Landsat images in Earth Engine. Night images will have a negative sun elevation indicating that the sun was below the horizon at the acquisition time. Other properties like `SCENE_CENTER_TIME` and methods like `filterDate` and `ee.Filter.calendarRange` are based on UTC time, making it difficult to find nighttime images across different time zones.

Note that night images are almost always excluded from Level 2 and Tier 1 collections, so a collection like [Tier 2 TOA](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/LANDSAT_LC08_C02_T2_TOA) is usually the best choice.

Here's a quick [demo script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/0870d111e165f5c29b0daa19fa227031) that loads a night image and visualizes the thermal IR band:

```js
// Select images where the sun is below the horizon
var night_images = l8
  .filterBounds(geometry)
  .filter(ee.Filter.lt("SUN_ELEVATION", 0));

var image = night_images.first()

// Print the local time of the image acquistion
print(image.date().update({timeZone: "America/Los_Angeles"}));

// Add the thermal infrared band to the map with a custom color palette
var magma = ['000004', '2C105C', '711F81', 'B63679', 'EE605E', 'FDAE78', 'FCFDBF'];
Map.addLayer(image, {min: 285, max: 295, bands: ["B11"], palette: magma});
```

[image: Thermal infrared Landsat imagery over Los Angeles]